# How come monitoring the status of a write to USB isn't reliable?

Tags: linux, usb, usb-flash-drive, iso-image, dd

I write ISO files to USB thumb drives a lot, and I'm trying to find a way to monitor the status of a write. Googling this, I have found a bunch of solutions, including `pv`, `dcfldd` and the USR1 signal to the `dd` command.

In all cases, this seems to be the case:

1. The file is written to the thumb drive at ca 100 MB/s
2. The transfer finishes (or possibly freezes at 99.99%) in less than 10 seconds
3. The transfer command remains unresponsive for *several minutes*, not even responding to interrupts
4. The transfer finishes

The behavior I expect would be a relatively slow write, perhaps around 5 MB/s, and a progress bar that progresses evenly from 0% to 100%. It seems to be that the file is written quickly into a buffer of some kind, then slowly flushed to disk afterwards.

Here are some commands I have tried, all with basically the same outcome:

```
# function vdd {
>     sudo dd "$@" &
>     sudo sh -c "while pkill -10 ^dd$; do sleep 5; done"
> }
# vdd bs=4096 if="/path/to/ubuntu-15.04-desktop-amd64.iso" of=/dev/sdb
```

```
dcfldd bs=4096 if="/path/to/ubuntu-15.04-desktop-amd64.iso" of=/dev/sdb
```

```
pv "/path/to/ubuntu-15.04-desktop-amd64.iso" | dd bs=4096 of=/dev/sdb
```

```
pv -B 4096 "/path/to/ubuntu-15.04-desktop-amd64.iso" > /dev/sdb
```

I have searched the man pages for `dd`, `pv` and `dcfldd` for the word "flush" with no results...

Comment: I have not seen this on USB transfers, but I have found network transfers particularly prone. When I examine the state of the transfer I find it in non-interruptible I/O, and it is a network driver limitation. I suspect a similar problem with USB, maybe caused by poor hand-shaking in the pen drive, possibly aggravated by retries after write errors. If this is so, I cannot image that any progress monitor would work.

Comment: @AFH I hope that's not the case... It's a shame to have a USB 3.0 stick that I can write to at over 100 MB/s, only to have it reduced to an effective 5 MB/s due to it freezing.

Comment: I agree, but I've always found pen drives and SD cards a lot less reliable than USB discs, especially when they fill up, though I have not had much of a problem in cameras, maybe because of slower write rates.

Answer (score 1):

If you need it for a cli tool

```
USB="/dev/sdb"
ISO_IMAGE="/path/to/ubuntu-15.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
SIZE=$(du -h -B1 "$ISO_IMAGE" | awk '{print $1}')

dd if="$ISO_IMAGE" | pv -s "$SIZE" | dd of="$USB" bs=4M oflag=dsync
```

Here dd will ask for completely synchronous output to disk.

You've mentioned flush, you probably want to use it for some UI to write out progress line by line with `pv -n`.

```
 USB="/dev/sdb"
 ISO_IMAGE="/path/to/ubuntu-15.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
 SIZE=$(du -h -B1 "$ISO_IMAGE" | awk '{print $1}')

 (dd if="$ISO_IMAGE" | pv -n -s "$SIZE" | dd of="$USB" bs=4M oflag=dsync) 2>&1 | \
  yad --center --borders=6 --title="Image writer" --text="$(echo -e "Writing $(basename "$ISO_IMAGE"):")"\
        --width=300 --progress --no-buttons --auto-close --image=system-run --window-icon=drive-removable-media-usb
```